# Can I decrypt openssl encrypted data using any dependancy?

Tags: python, encryption, openssl

I have used `openssl` to encrypt data using below command:

```
openssl cms -encrypt -in test.data -inform PEM -recip certificate.pem -outform PEM -out test_encrypted_data.txt
```

Now I want to decrypt above encrypted data using python. I have tried below code, but it is not working and is throwing:

```
ValueError: Ciphertext with incorrect length.
```

Code:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP, AES
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from OpenSSL import crypto

import base64

data = open("test_encrypted_data.txt").read()
data = data.replace("-----BEGIN CMS-----", "").replace("-----END CMS-----", "")
data = base64.b64decode(data)
private_key = RSA.import_key(open("private_key_no_pass.pem").read())
decryptor = PKCS1_OAEP.new(private_key)
decryptedtext = decryptor.decrypt(data)
print(f"Decrypted Text : {decryptedtext.decode()}")
```

Comment: Thanks all I have used openssl commands to decrypt file in python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all I have used openssl commands to decrypt file in python

```
decrypted_data = subprocess.check_output(
            f'echo "{encryptedtext}" | openssl cms -decrypt -inkey services/private_key_no_pass.pem -inform PEM ',
            shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if openssl des 'base64' encode.

Probably -base64 parameter is missing in openssl.

So the text is encrypted but not base64 coded by openssl, and then your code does base64 decode and decrypts it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I have tried without base64 also still same result but if I use openssl command then it work but not on Python :-(

openssl cms -decrypt -inkey private_key_no_pass.pem -in test_encrypted_data.txt -out test_decrypted_data.txt -inform PEM

Comment: You should use base64 in both cases, so in openssl and in Python... Did you try that combination?

Comment: I have used other way without base64 for encryption(openssl) and decryption(python) if you have any document reference please share thanks